# How is Mootools loaded?

Tags: javascript, mootools

A javascript component on my site has stopped working. While debugging I found out it conflicted with Mootools. Only then I realize Mootools is loaded on my page. I remember reading an article saying that in recent Joomla versions, Mootools is no longer loaded, why then it is loaded on my page? Also I was able to find an archive of the page in question http://web-old.archive.org/web/20210227182023/https://cchc-herald.org/about-us and on this page Mootools is not loaded and the javascript component works fine.

I've made a very simple testing page ( a "single article" page) https://cchc-herald.org/debug and you can see that even on this page Mootools is loaded. I can't remember doing anything that could cause Mootools to be loaded. Could anyone please help me find out?

I need to find out why it is loaded, please don't simply tell me to get an extension to disable it.

By the way, I keep Joomla updated on a weekly basis. So my site always has the latest Joomla version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Joomla it's possible to load JavaScript libraries via different ways, via:

- your template
- a component
- a (system) plugin
- a module

When it's loaded on every page, it's usually loaded via your template or a plugin.

Could you test your site with the default Protostar template?
If it's still loaded, then it's probably a system plugin.

If it isn't loaded with Protostar, then it's probably your current template (or a template override in your current template).

See also:

- [Clean way to disable MooTools in my back-end component or workarounds?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9963/clean-way-to-disable-mootools-in-my-back-end-component-or-workarounds)
- [Remove unwanted Joomla Scripts in version 3.8.x curious not working](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23473/remove-unwanted-joomla-scripts-in-version-3-8-x-curious-not-working)

Comment: Thanks I have found the plugin that loads Mootools